# The Q.A.P. Puzzle

Tags: riddle, word

> Q.A.P.
>
> Quandary Actuated Perpetually
>
> A very difficult puzzle.

4

Although, it is not always what one desires, it keeps you safe.

How am I able to find the source of all this chaos surrounding me? After all, even I am not able to find how one must begin. The beginning of the cycle, or should I say square, no, cube, of all that comes and goes are the faces of the shadows within.

The beginning of the difference of the one above and the one at level could be the answer. Yet, I should count 5 more after it.

Corrected time and time again, who knew it would always come to me?

Shall I search for something that appears not twice but once? Shall the answer be one that precedes and one that is ahead? I shall search yet again.

Being not behind, but _____, subtract a, then find the whole ÷ 4

Hints if you actually need any:

> The answer is a single word. Follow along with the clues from top to bottom.

Comment: I like to use google.

Comment: Can we have more hints

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I'm just going to go for it.

> Pi

4

> 3.14 is kinda 4...ish?

Although it is not always what one desires, it keeps you safe.

> A lot of people don't like working with Pi, but it is a major component in engineering and physics.

How am I able to find the source of all this chaos surrounding me? After all, even I am not able to find how one must begin. The beginning of the cycle, or should I say square, no, cube, of all that comes and goes are the faces of the shadows within.

> How can you find the beginning of a circle? Where do you begin to measure? Pi squared is used in the surface area of circles and Pi cubed in the volume of spheres.

The beginning of the difference of the one above and the one at level could be the answer. Yet, I should count 5 more after it.

> 

Corrected time and time again, who knew it would always come to me?

> It took a while to find pi.

Shall I search for something that appears not twice but once? Shall the answer be one that precedes and one that is ahead? I shall search yet again.

> Should we use an old definition of pi? Or... How many digits of pi should I use?

Being not behind, but _____, subtract a, then find the whole ÷ 4

> 

Comment: Have to admit, you did a lot of research on this... Even though it isn't correct, I have to give you credit for the effort.

Comment: @OmegaLul Please upvote the answer for encouraging more people to give credit :)

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> By solving the "math" behind this:

4

> 4

Although, it is not always what one desires, it keeps you safe.

> Not sure

How am I able to find the source of all this chaos surrounding me? After all, even I am not able to find how one must begin. The beginning of the cycle, or should I say square, no, cube, of all that comes and goes are the faces of the shadows within.

> 4 cubed is 64

The beginning of the difference of the one above and the one at level could be the answer. Yet, I should count 5 more after it.

> The difference of the one above (65) and the one at level (64) is 1, then +5 = 6

Corrected time and time again, who knew it would always come to me?

> ??

Shall I search for something that appears not twice but once? Shall the answer be one that precedes and one that is ahead? I shall search yet again.

> 6-1=5, 6+1=7. So 57

Being not behind, but _____, subtract a, then find the whole ÷ 4

> 57 / 4 = 14.25, not sure about "subtract a"

Comment: I like how much math there is in this (even though I hate math). It isn't the answer, but keep going!

Answer (score 2):

4

> 4 years for presidential election cycle (in USA)

Although, it is not always what one desires, it keeps you safe.

> Who really wants a president?

How am I able to find the source of all this chaos surrounding me? After all, even I am not able to find how one must begin. The beginning of the cycle, or should I say square, no, cube, of all that comes and goes are the faces of the shadows within.

> something to do with the election process?

The beginning of the difference of the one above and the one at level could be the answer. Yet, I should count 5 more after it.

> ?

Corrected time and time again, who knew it would always come to me?

> President bears the brunt of blame?

Shall I search for something that appears not twice but once? Shall the answer be one that precedes and one that is ahead? I shall search yet again.

> Something to do with Grover Cleveland

Being not behind, but _____, subtract a, then find the whole ÷ 4

> ahead - a = head. whole/4 = quarter -> Washington?

Answer:

> President?

Comment: Your answer sure is unique! You did pretty well, although it isn't the correct answer.